# How to remove icons from the Ubuntu application grid

Tags: ubuntu

I installed League Of Legends on my ubuntu 22.04 through lutris using wine. I have now uninstalled it using lutris again. Although it has left behind the League Of Legends and the Riot Client app icons in the ubuntu application grid. I want to remove them and i don't know how. Any ideas?

Answer (score 15):

Application icons in ubuntu are stored into `.desktop` files. You can find these files in the directories `/usr/share/applications` and `~/.local/share/applications`.
Wine stores its application icons into `~/.local/share/applications/wine`. Just delete the LeagueOfLegends/RiotGames .desktop file in there.

Comment: Thanks, man! I just removed the uninstalled wine applications icons.

Comment: My hero! <3 You Rock @drewka